# TinyMCE: Clear editor content when repaste from word

Tags: html, tinymce, textarea

I have a tinyMCE editor on my textarea. I am using often the paste from word button and I would like to clear the content of the editor when I am repasting from word.

Do you have an idea on how to do this.

Comment: what do you mean by "clear the content of the editor"? do you want to remove all the previous editor content and just keep the pasted stuff in your editor?

Comment: @Thariama, thank you for your answer. You're right, that's what I need. I have found an answer which works well, I will pot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. On intialization of the tinyMCE, I ovveriden the paste_postprocess:

```
        paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
        // Content string containing the HTML from the clipboard
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
        return tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(pl);
        }
```